# Groovy eclipse plugin, strikethroughs everywhere

Tags: eclipse, groovy, syntax-highlighting

I just tried the Groovy-Eclipse plugin , and everything is working fine, except the syntax highlighting is behaving really strange.

Basically, it sees to think pretty much everything is deprecated. I get strike-troughs everywhere.

For example, toURL is striked through when using

```
 "http://stackoverflow.com".toURL()
```

I see this with loads of methods, including eachLine , getText and many many more. These methods aren't deprecated, what is going on?

I'm running Eclipse 4.2, 2.7.0.xx-20120703-1400-e42-RELEASE and Groovy 2.0

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What version of the Groovy plugin? What version of Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are deprecated because they moved to other classes and your plugin is not aware of that. There're many methods deprecated:

You can look up the deprecated API's for the new main version of Groovy [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/deprecated-list.html).

You can read about the similar question [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/DefaultGroovyMethods-deprecated-td5710664.html):

---

> An answer from the STS/Groovy-Eclipse side of things.
>   This is fixed in the latest 2.7.1 snapshot.
>       Earlier versions of Groovy-Eclipse were not aware of StringGroovyMethod,
>       but this has been fixed.

---

Comment: That's right.  You can update using the following update sites.  For E37: http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/ For E42: http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e4.2/